# Where/how is the global tolower defined and what other similar functions exist?

Tags: c++

This code compiles successfully, and <s>that's because I am apparently using the "global namespace" version of `tolower` (as opposed to either of the versions that live in `<cctype>` or `<locale>`)</s> actually i'm not sure?.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string x = "FOO";
  std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), tolower);
}
```

My questions:

1) Where/how is this `tolower` established exactly?

2) Can someone direct me to a list of all such "global namespace" functions?

I've actually spent a fair amount of time seeking an answer; apologies if this is obvious knowledge and I missed it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower

Comment: It's probably pulled in indirectly via one of the other headers (in an implementation-defined manner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some compilers provide declarations from `<c__>` headers (from C standard library) in both `std::` and global namespace. As @chris said, this is allowed by the standard, but there are no guarantees. Thus, you should not rely on it.

Comment: It's conforming behaviour to include declarations in both namespaces, but not guaranteed by any means.

Comment: @chris Thanks, added.